# How can I get Twitter-Bootstrap 3's navbar to work in mobile and desktop view justified?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

So I wanted to get the bootstrap 3 navbars links justified/centered. I asked this community why when applying `.nav-justified` it conflicted with `.navbar-nav`. those two should not be applied with each other because

> The .nav-justifed class is to be used with nav-tabs / nav-pills (see
>   bootstrap docs) and not nav-bar. The two concepts are very different
>   and should not be confused.
>
> However, you can achieve the effect you are looking for by adding the
>   following css:
>
> .navbar-nav.nav-justified > li{
>       float:none; } nav-justifiednow plays nice with navbar-nav:

What he suggested worked perfectly, only that when I use a responsive navbar, where it will collapse  on a mobile view, the links stay horizontally aligned in the mobile view, instead of  them being listed vertically.

I have prepared a fiddle just in case you are a little confused.

The first navbar does not have the `.nav-justified` applied to it, so it works fine when using mobile view. But the links are not centered, they're pulled to the left.

The second navbar does have the `.nav-justified` so the links are centered, however when using mobile view the links are still centered, and not listed vertically like the first navbar.

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

[Jsfiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XKPpT/)

Comment: Your jsFiddle does not seem to display any links. Please fix it so that we can help you solve your issue.

Comment: @edsioufi
Please litterally click where it says "Jsfiddle Here" That word in blue is the link.

Comment: Yes I know but the jsFiddle does not display any links. Seems the HTML structure is not correct. Are you sure the links should be in a `navbar-collapse` tab?